# Is it okay to replace "proclaim" with "claim" here?

Tags: word-choice

This sentence is from *Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind*.

> THE AGRICULTURAL REVOLUTION IS ONE of the most controversial events in
> history. Some partisans **proclaim** that it set humankind on the road to
> prosperity and progress. Others insist that it led to perdition.

I'm wondering if the word "proclaim" can be replaced with "claim".

Edit: I asked this question because I'm confused about "proclaim" vs "claim". My main confusion is whether the two can be used interchangeably. One difference I do know is that "claim" indicates "typically without providing evidence or proof". But I'm not sure "to announce something" is the same as "to state or assert that something is the case".

Comment: Please show your research into *proclaim* and *claim.* What caused you to ask this question? Currently the question invites the answers "Yes" and "No" which means at the very least it needs to be worded better; any background you have will enable fuller answers to be given.

Comment: I looked up "proclaim" in dictionary which says it means "announce". "claim" seems more suitable to me. I asked the question to be sure.

Comment: Please edit that into the question. Also, **why** does *claim* seem more suitable? Is there any reason why the authors could not have meant *proclaim*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Proclaim*** can mean

> to announce something publicly or officially, to show something or make it clear ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proclaim))

It makes a statement about the manner in which someone announces something, about their conviction, so it is a characterisation of the subject (partisans) and says little about the author of the sentence.

***Claim***, however, would be accusatory and point to the author's skepticism as to the truth of the assertion of those partisans. *Claim* means:

> to say that something is true or is a fact, although you cannot prove it and other people might not believe it:
>
> - He claims to have met the president, but I don't believe him. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/claim))

So, no, you cannot replace *proclaim* with *claim*, without changing the meaning, more particularly, without an impact on the neutrality of the author.

Comment: I don't disagree with the answer to the question as stated. However I would guess that the author of the passage actually meant to say "claim" as it is seems to be a discussion about the views of historians and their claims.

Comment: Both "proclaim" and "insist" should be replaced by "claim" according to you, and there is a level where all these verbs do overlap. But in my understanding both "proclaim" and "insist" show the author's intent to efface himself and stay neutral. Of course, it is a matter of interpretation.

Comment: I can see that a historian who had a personal investment in a particular reading of history, and made no secret of it, might be said to "proclaim" their views. On reflection the fact that the author uses the the rather pejorative term "partisans" makes it quite possible that he did mean to write "proclaim" as a (rather stronger) alternative to "insist" to avoid double use of "insist".

Comment: I think the excerpt is a case where both *proclaim* and *claim* could apply. *Proclaim* because they are making a forceful proclamation of a matter of great importance with utter certainty and in a manner which isn't genuinely official but may seem to have the characteristics of an official proclamation, *claim* because it's debatable. But just because two words can be used in the same place once doesn't mean they are always interchangable. Some proclamations are dubious (I could stand in the street and proclaim myself emperor), others are not.